# Repeated SMB QUERY_PATH_INFO Packets for Windows file share

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-share, server-message-block, windows-server-2000

This is related to my previous question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/85678/printing-with-old-application-win2000-is-slow), but I have narrowed it down and want to open another one.

I have windows 2000 server on its own domain, there is no trust between the clients domain and the windows 2000 server.  With two Windows 2003 Enterprise clients in the same subnet I map the Windows 2003 file system that is another subnet as a network drive using map as different user and 'OLDDOMAIN\auser'.

One of those Windows 2003 clients is a domain controller for NewDomain, and the other is not a domain controller at all.  The one that is a domain controller is not slow, the one that is not a domain controller is slow.

When I do a packet dump from each client, the one that is slow, the non-domain controller, has repeated SMB QUERY_PATH_INFO packets when accessing the file whereas the domain controller only has a couple of these messages. ipconfig /all shows the same results (with a different ip of course) on both clients.  Neither have olddomain in their search path, or any WINs settings in the ipconfig output.

Comment: Lots of Query_FILE_INFO as well

Comment: We've got a Win 7 machine which is hitting our SBS2003 DC with loads and loads of requests for query_file_info repeatedly, for no good reason it seems. Wireshark on the server shows these packets again and again, stumped as to why they're happening though, did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, you stated in your other post that one of the machines in question was running NT4. Is that right? If so, these may or may not be relevant, but they're worth a look:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888562

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/265396

Comment: Had seen both of them, not sure if either seem to be spot on... Also doesn't really explain the different between the DC and non-Dc results.

Comment: This does smell like an oplocks or SMB signing issue.  How about this one?  It helps explain SMB signing and how to check a packet capture for it.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/887429